# Mirrored the object then its edges got intertwined with Original

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

I was creating Human Model, Started with a cube cut it in half then mirrored, and started extrude, scale, rotate etc, when i reached at neck i noticed that original cube's faces/edges got itertwined with mirror object.
When i try to move vertices and edges manually and snap with mirror object it again does not work for me.
This will cause problem for me while joining neck with torso.
What do you think? i should be doing.
[image]
[image]

Comment: make sure that the Clipping option is enabled in the Mirror modifier, and also make sure that your vertices are on the good side, not the mirrored side

Comment: Thank you, It Helped!